# Shopify - started getting 404 exceptions when updating variants

Tags: shopify

i've had my first Shopify store running for about a month now, using a PHP batch script to either create new products and variants, or to update as and when needed from an existing web-based product management system. All seems to have been running fine but i've just noticed that i'm getting an exception thrown when updating variants. I'm sure this has been working fine previously (been able to update a variant as needed) so I could do with a bit of help figuring out why this is failing now.

Here's an example:

```
ShopifyApiException Object
(
[method:protected] => PUT
[path:protected] => /admin/variants/4294967295.json
[params:protected] => Array
    (
        [variant] => Array
            (
                [price] => 8.00
                [sku] => 2217
                [id] => 2217
                [product_id] => 21880
                [inventory_management] => shopify
                [inventory_policy] => deny
                [inventory_quantity] => 1
                [option1] => Plain \/ EX
                [option2] => Strictly Rhythm
                [option3] => SR12216
                [weight] => 330
                [weight_unit] => g
            )

    )

[response_headers:protected] => Array
    (
        [http_status_message] => Not Found
        [http_status_code] => 404
        [server] => nginx
        [date] => Fri, 21 Aug 2015 14:27:03 GMT
        [content-type] => application/json; charset=utf-8
        [transfer-encoding] => chunked
        [connection] => keep-alive
        [vary] => Accept-Encoding
        [x-sorting-hat-podid] => 3
        [x-sorting-hat-shopid] => 2234339
        [x-sorting-hat-podid-cached] => 1
        [x-sorting-hat-shopid-cached] => 1
        [status] => 404 Not Found
        [x-frame-options] => DENY
        [x-shopid] => 2234339
        [x-shardid] => 3
        [x-shopify-shop-api-call-limit] => 1/40
        [http_x_shopify_shop_api_call_limit] => 1/40
        [x-stats-userid] => 0
        [x-stats-apiclientid] => 152673
        [x-stats-apipermissionid] => 3265975
        [x-xss-protection] => 1; mode=block; report=/xss-report/97471013-3a3c-4b82-a94d-868f9b7ac073?source%5Baction%5D=update&source%5Bcontroller%5D=admin%2Fproduct_variants&source%5Bsection%5D=admin
        [set-cookie] => request_method=PUT; path=/
        [x-request-id] => 97471013-3a3c-4b82-a94d-868f9b7ac073
    )

[response:protected] => Array
    (
        [errors] => Not Found
    )

[message:protected] => Not Found
[string:Exception:private] =>
[code:protected] => 404
[file:protected] => /var/www/MY-SERVER/httpdocs/shopify_tools/shopify.php
[line:protected] => 70
[trace:Exception:private] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [file] => /var/www/MY-SERVER/httpdocs/shopify_tools/batch_upload_items.php
                [line] => 347
                [function] => call
                [class] => ShopifyClient
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => PUT
                        [1] => /admin/variants/4294967295.json
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [variant] => Array
                                    (
                                        [price] => 8.00
                                        [sku] => 2217
                                        [id] => 2217
                                        [product_id] => 21880
                                        [inventory_management] => shopify
                                        [inventory_policy] => deny
                                        [inventory_quantity] => 1
                                        [option1] => Plain \/ EX
                                        [option2] => Strictly Rhythm
                                        [option3] => SR12216
                                        [weight] => 330
                                        [weight_unit] => g
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[previous:Exception:private] =>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've realised the problem - hopefully this may help someone else.

I was storing the Shopify Variant ID in an INT column in my database and Shopify Variant IDs have just recently passed the INT limit of 4294967295 - switching to BIGINT and reimporting all the Variant IDs solved the problem.